# Instantiating Swift class from text on server

Tags: ios, swift

I have an iOS app in which I'd like to implement a subscription model. However, the items that a user would be purchasing require me to write new Swift classes every so often.

I would love to not have to rely on users updating the app to see the new content. Is there a way to instantiate a class from an arbitrary text file at build time that I could potentially deploy from a server?

Edit: I've come back to reality since reading your comments, but I'll also add some code to clarify my use case. Maybe there's another solution I'm missing.

Essentially, the "assets" in this app are algorithmically generated pieces of music. So an item might contain AudioKit nodes connected together. I may have a class like this:

```
class sawtooth:sound {
    var pwmOscillator:AKPWMOscillator? // = AKTable(.sawtooth, count: 4_096)
    var countDownToNextPitch:Double
    var sawtoothTwo:AKTable
    var oscillatorTwo:AKOscillator
    var lpf:AKLowPassFilter

    // ... instantiate more nodes and parameters
    init (filterFactor: Double) {
        self.pwmOscillator = AKPWMOscillator(frequency: 32.7031956626)
        self.pwmOscillator?.pulseWidth = 0.2
        self.sawtoothTwo = AKTable(.sawtooth, count: 4_096)
        self.oscillatorTwo = AKOscillator(waveform: sawtoothTwo)
        self.oscillatorTwo.frequency = 65.4063913251
        self.oscillatorTwo.amplitude = 0
        self.chorusMixer = AKMixer(self.pwmOscillator!, self.oscillatorTwo)
       // ...etc.
    }

    func behavior(atTime:Double, withProgramInstance:program) {
        // Add parameters that define how sound evolves with time
    }
}
```

It would be great to deploy some of this stuff without needing a hard update. But if that's impossible, it's impossible.

Comment: It isn't clear why you need to create a new class for every item. This is definitely wrong and you are heading the wrong direction. But to help you it would be helpful to see the relevant parts of your code to understand your misconception.

Comment: You cant download and use Swift files in a live app if thats what you mean. The app has to be compiled into a ipa file, which then needs to be reviewed by Apple.

Comment: I'm afraid this is both impossible and discouraged by Apple.

Comment: Oh duh! Of course this would be discouraged by Apple, I didn't even think of that. I'm not sure what code I would post that would be helpful, I haven't written anything in this direction yet.

Comment: Updated to clarify. Thanks for your comments so far.

Comment: Maybe a more abstract class with some base properties and an options dictionary of type `[String : String]` or `[String : Any]` would work better. So you can add more nodes dynamically which have different behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you're using subscription model, your app must already have all that is necessary to provide a premium content. The only solution I see is to have models on your client-side that can be configured by a server-side. To simplify:

Consider you have an asset you want to enable when user buys it.
Let's say you have a model class like this

```
class Asset {
    var id: Int
    var nodes: [MyNode]

    func connect(to: SomeObject) {
      {...} //Some nodes related logic etc 
    }
}

class MyNode {
    var type: MyNodeType
    var oscillator: Oscillator
    var {...}
}
```

Basically what you do is get configurations for your assets from your backend for example in JSON. Then you just create your objects from this configuration files. There's no need to actually hardcode everything in the app, you just need a proper reusable models for your nodes. That you can get from server.

Comment: This makes sense to me. I'll look into abstracting the data models into something more flexible, but my sense is that (since we want to maximize creativity for our premium content) we may not want to try and account for every possibility in advance. We may end up just having to push monthly updates. Thanks!

Comment: You're right. The level of abstraction for your models will set the borders. But in most cases creating new instruments will lead to creating new models which will result in `some` updates for the app from time to time. You can still predict the most common scenarios and build your app from that.